# How to build multi level navigation with PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, navigation, html-lists

Im working on a prototype, and would like to build a multi level navigation - however not by looping through an array. I have a $depth and a $children, which should determine the depth of the navigation and the number of children on each level. So $depth = 4, $children = 8 would yield 4096 menu items.

This is a snippet af the output I would like:

```
<ul>
    <li class="level-1">
        <a href="#">Subject 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="level-2">
                <a href="#">Subject 1.1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="level-3">
                        <a href="#">Subject 1.1.1</a>
                    </li>
                    ...
                </ul>
            </li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

So far I have tried this, but I cant get my head around it :(

```
function draw_list ($depth, $children) {

  echo '<ul>';

  for ($i = 0; $i < $children; $i++) {

    echo '<li>' . ($i++);

    $depth--;

    if ($depth > 0) {

      echo draw_list($depth, $children);

    }

    echo '</li>';

  }

  echo '</ul>';


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things required as I see it...

- The `$depth--;` needs to be outside of the `for` loop
- You were incrementing `$i` twice, once in the `for` statement, and then again on the `echo '<li>' . ($i++);`
- <strike>The $depth check was stopping one early, so make `>=` instead of just `>`</strike> (**Edit**, thinking about it, this is an incorrect statement)

That should give you...

```
function draw_list ($depth, $children) {  
  echo '<ul>';
  $depth--;
  for ($i = 0; $i < $children; $i++) {
    echo '<li>' . $i;
    if ($depth > 0) {
      echo draw_list($depth, $children);
    }
    echo '</li>';
  }
  echo '</ul>';
}
```

**Update**

For the display of the level numbering, try passing a string value through as a parameter...

```
function draw_list ($depth, $children, $display=''){  
  echo '<ul>';
  $depth--;
  for ($i = 0; $i < $children; $i++) {
    echo '<li>' . $display . ($i + 1);
    if ($depth > 0) {
      echo draw_list($depth, $children, $display . ($i + 1) . '.');
    }
    echo '</li>';
  }
  echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I need to figure out how to print the level numbers (1.3.3.7 etc). I properly have to build an array and implode. Any ideas?

Comment: @tolborg, Add string parameter, in the for loop create new sting using the parameter and the child index which you display and then pass as parameter in the recursion

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```
function build_nav ($depth, $children, $levels = array()) {

    echo '<ul>';
    $depth--;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $children; $i++) {

        $levels[$depth] = $i+1;

        echo '<li>';
        echo 'Subject: ' . implode('.', $levels); 

        if ($depth > 0) {
            build_nav($depth, $children, $levels);
        }
        echo '</li>';
    } 
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: If it works, it works. But it looks to me like you're setting the array at the wrong level, as depth will decrease not increase. Also you've made me realise that my example will have the values one too low